# Apply PCA on specific columns with Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

i am trying to apply PCA on a dataset that contains a header and contains fields 
Here is the code i used , any help to be able to select a specific columns on which we apply PCA .

```
val inputMatrix = sc.textFile("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/Realase of 01_06_2017/TopDrive_WithoutConstant.csv").map { line =>
  val values = line.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
  Vectors.dense(values)
}

val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(inputMatrix)
val pc: Matrix = mat.computePrincipalComponents(4)
// Project the rows to the linear space spanned by the top 4 principal components.

val projected: RowMatrix = mat.multiply(pc)
```

//updated version 
i tried to do this

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val dataframe = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")

val columnsToUse: Seq[String] =  Array("Col0","Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4").toSeq
val k: Int = 2

val df = spark.read.format("csv").options(Map("header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true")).load("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/donnee/cassandraTest_1.csv")

val rf = new RFormula().setFormula(s"~ ${columnsToUse.mkString(" + ")}")
val pca = new PCA().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("pcaFeatures").setK(k)

val featurized = rf.fit(df).transform(df)
//prinpal component
val principalComponent = pca.fit(featurized).transform(featurized)
principalComponent.select("pcaFeatures").show(4,false)

+-----------------------------------------+
|pcaFeatures                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
|[-0.536798281241379,0.495499034754084]   |
|[-0.32969328815797916,0.5672811417154808]|
|[-1.32283465170085,0.5982789033642704]   |
|[-0.6199718696225502,0.3173072633712586] |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I got this for pricipal component , the question i want to save this in csv file and add header.Any help many thanks 
Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks a lot

Comment: Tell me how it goes !

Comment: @eliasah please check what i add as edited question

Comment: I'm not sure I get the update... It seems like a new question for me and not an update. If so, please accept the answer and ask a new question

Comment: @eliasah would you please try to help save the result into a csv file thanks

Comment: what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: @eliasah i am using  2.0.2 , i would like to save the result as i said and add a header  to the file ,many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RFormula` in this case :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{RFormula, PCA}

val columnsToUse: Seq[String] = ???
val k: Int = ???

val df = spark.read.format("csv").options(Map("header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true")).load("/tmp/foo.csv")

val rf = new RFormula().setFormula(s"~ ${columnsToUse.mkString(" + ")}")
val pca = new PCA().setInputCol("features").setK(k)

val featurized = rf.fit(df).transform(df)
val projected = pca.fit(featurized).transform(featurized)
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "DateTime"`

it means that in your input file there is a value `DateTime` that you then try to convert to `Double`.

Probably it is somewhere in the header of you input file

Comment: yes i know , what i want is to select specefic columns from the input file, how can i have a specific columns selected , thank you.Any help